# how to verify if the directory exists and read/writable in java

Tags: java

I want to know how to verify if there given directory path exists and need to verify the following.

1)directory is readable ?

2)directory is writable ?

3)if writable, create a file in that file,write some content to that file and then delete that file.

I read canWrite() method is not appropriate because even there are no permissions on that directory it still returns true.
I read there are `java.io.FilePermissions`,but there may be few `SecurityExceptions`, Please

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html

Comment: ya i read that, but i am looking for example. also As i mentioned, other posts,says, if security manager enabled on that system,it was not working

Comment: i guess you should than elaborate a "bit" more of what you know and make your question more precise. including a statement/program which reflects this knowledge. now your question just says. do my work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that an attempt to create a file in a directory is going to succeed.

- Even if you could determine that a directory is writeable, some other program could change something that causes that to no longer to be true ... an instant later.
- On some systems (e.g. Linux with SELinux in "enforcing" mode), a Java application does not know (and can't find out) about all of the preconditions for a successful creation.
- The Java security sandbox has a say in the issue ... if your application is sandboxed.

The simplest and safest solution is to just attempt to create the file, and deal with the exceptions if it fails.

Comment: yes I have already done in this way. just check if directory path exists, then create file and delete.

Comment: That's NOT what I advised.  **Don't** check if the directory path exists, etc.  Just attempt to create file and catch the exceptions.  The value of checking that the directory path exists would be if your application spec required you to create directories is the path didn't exist.  That's not what you said in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`java.nio.file`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package.It has all that you need and more.